# Converting Lines (Strokes) to Paths like in Inkscape before exporting as PDF

Tags: qgis, line, inkscape

I'm having a very hard time exporting line maps that end up looking and working correctly when importing into Inkscape/Affinity Designer. What I am trying to do in QGIS before exporting is basically this:

Set line stroke width > Combine lines into one > convert line(s) to path (Basically a fill without strokes) > Export

I understand that I am probably using the wrong vernacular for QGIS, but this is the best way that I know how to describe the process.

Here is the result that I get now when importing either the PDF or SVG into Inkscape:
[image]

Even after rounding my "Join and Caps", it still looks weird and bubbly.

I also attempted to export as a DXF to import into Affinity Designer and this is the result:
[image]

Comment: What do those lines look like in QGIS's layout, and in the exported pdf, prior to import to Inkscape.  Have you tried smoothing your lines first?

Comment: When I add the map in "New Print Layout", the map looks ok, just pixelated when you zoom in. Smoothing seems to just add more noise since a bunch of extra nodes get added when using that algorithm.

Comment: I have assumed you wanted to export vectors in your pdf for use in Inkscape.  If your layout is truly showing pixelated shapes you have somehow rasterized your lines in QGIS, let alone in the export process.  I'm not sure what you did when you say you converted lines to path in QGIS.  What if you just make your maps and symbolize your lines the way you want, then export to pdf with the always export as vectors option selected?

Comment: I haven't yet converted my lines to paths, that's my goal. I'm not sure if I can even do that in QGIS. Is it possible to symbolize my lines as polygons? Basically, I want the line itself to become a polygon without changing its entire shape. Also, I'm honestly not sure how I would've rasterized my lines.

Comment: If you want polygons just buffer your lines a small amount using the buffer tool.  See vector geometry or GDAL vector geoprocessing  If you want a single polygon use the dissolve option.

Comment: Ok, so I tried using dissolve and it worked within QGIS, though after importing the SVG into Inkscape, all of the lines are just grouped and not dissolved/welded within Inkscape. I also have tried using buffer but I can't seem to get the hang of it. After executing I just get massive polygons that pop up over my lines to the point that I can't even see them.

Comment: What coordinate system is your project in?  Your buffer experience suggests you may be in a geographic system, like WGS 84, and when you pick the buffer units those are in degrees and would produce massive polys.  Or you are picking the wrong distance units.  If you can I would suggest converting your lines to a projected system, such as a UTM Nad 83 zone appropriate for your location.  You can just export/save as your lines and in the dialog box pick the CRS.  Then buffer those with an appropriate unit.  I would do it in a new project if you can; you can add them back to your old if needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142619/discussion-between-nick-and-john).

Answer (score 3):

With "paths" you probably mean vector lines. The problem in your case is where two line features touch each other. To avoid the problem, simply merge all lines of a vector layer so that you have only one feature left. Use <kbd>Merge Selected Features</kbd> icon in the toolbar or access it via Menu <kbd>Processing</kbd> > <kbd>Toolbox</kbd> > <kbd>Merge Selected Features</kbd>.

Apart from that, smoothing the lines - e.g. using Geometry Generator with `smooth($geometry, 5)` - or simplifying the lines could help, too.

[image]

---

Be aware: If the lines cannot be connected to one single part feature, but consist of multiple parts (e.g. if you have several disconnected lines or forking lines like in the letter **Y**), first create a new layer of geometry type MultiLine. Copy/past all lines to this layer, select all features and merge.

Comment: This did work with merging my lines in QGIS, however, when exporting as SVG, it imports into Inkscape as all separate lines grouped together instead of all "welded" together.