# Getting jagged lines when exporting SVG/PDF and importing into Inkscape/Affinity Designer

Tags: qgis, line, contour, inkscape

I'm having a lot of issues with exporting contour maps in QGIS. Once extracting contours from my SRTM data, I've tried cleaning up my lines in multiple ways before exporting as either .svg or .pdf. I've used "generalize", "smooth" and "simplified" all with various settings but hardly any acceptable results.

I've also set my join and cap styles as round, but that doesn't seem to fix the issues completely either. It seems to make the lines terribly bubbly as well. The closest I can get to what I want is to use "Buffer", but the issue with that is I can't edit the width once I open the file in Inscape/Affinity Designer.

My goal is to make an art print of the area that I've extracted contours from, but cannot seem to make them uniform/smooth enough for it to actually look nice.

[image: inkscape]

[image: inkscape]

Comment: Never has this issue, doing  the exact same thing. What do your lines look like in Qgis (visually and object wise)? Looks like many small separate line segments with a very large width

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with the various join style and end cap style options in QGIS before exporting? Perhaps using rounded would yield better results.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of your earlier posts, the first being https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/451247/converting-lines-strokes-to-paths-like-in-inkscape-before-exporting-as-pdf.  Instead of making additional posts you should go back to your original and edit that for what you have done, and so people can see the comments/answers from those earlier posts.

Comment: @Kasper All of my lines in QGIS are at 0.26 mm width. They look like they are separate segments in inkscape, but they look normal in QGIS. It seems like the main cause of the issue is nodes. When I move, edit, and delete the nodes that are causing the "spikes" in Inkscape, it makes the line look better. But I can't figure out why it's happening when I export from QGIS in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Once I simply changed my line widths to "map units" instead of "millimeters" it exported correctly.